# Retrieving Dates in MongoJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongojs

I'm trying to store and retrieve a date in mongojs. Here's how it's saved:

```
var game = { startedOn: new Date() };
db.games.save(game);
```

When I fetch it, the date is not a date anymore. It's some kind of wrapper around a date.  The `_d` field seems to be a date, but it's weird that I should have to access it that way.

```
db.games.find(function(err, games){
    console.log(game[0].startedOn);
});
```

This logs:

```
{ _useUTC: true,
  _isUTC: true,
  _l: null,
  _i: null,
  _f: null,
  _d: Sun Jun 09 2013 21:49:26 GMT-0500 (CDT) }
```

What's the right way to store/retrieve a date in mongo-js?

Comment: What's the `first` method that you're calling on the collection?  I don't see any reference to that in the MongoJS code.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks, i simplified the code for brevity. I'll update it

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) instance, although I can't reproduce getting one back using `mongojs`.

Comment: @robertklep it probably is - my first attempt to save dates was `moment().utc()`. I thought i deleted all that data, so maybe that's still haunting me. i'll check it out

Comment: @robertklep yep, it was a dangling moment. thanks for the help. To anyone that cares, dates *do* properly deserialize in mongojs as you would expect them to.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` and `Date` values should be converted to `UTC` Time  before storing them in MongoDB

The method you have above works fine in nodejs.

Here is how you retrieve it:

```
new Date(parseInt(this.toString().slice(0,8), 16)*1000);
```

More [info](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date)